# The given path's format is not supporte in C#

Tags: c#, file, io, path

I have this line of code:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(Path.Combine(@"pack://application:,,,/Images/", "test.png"), Convert.FromBase64String(staticImage.Base64));
```

This is my project structure:

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyHI3.jpg
```

And I call this code in the App.xaml.cs file. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What kind of application are you trying to do?
And what is the `pack` protocol used in your path?

Comment: @NicolasR It's a wpf application.

Comment: And you are trying to get the Images folder dynamically using this `pack://application`? I'm not sure that you can use this syntax in your code behind

Comment: Who do you want to write to a file using URIs? URI stands for Uniform Resource Identifiers, and resources are not meant to be changed at runtime. What are you exactly trying to achieve?